# UIAlert after progressView has reached a value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uialertview, uiprogressview

I am kind of lost here. I want to know how to implement an `UIAlertView` after my progressView has crossed a value of 0.8.

To be more clearer I have a `NSTimer` running in a background thread which updates a float variable and when the control returns to the main thread I update the value of the progressView.

I would like the `alertView` to stay in the foreground until user action.

Hope I am clear enough.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [Key-Value-Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH16-SW1) on the variable you are watching, and when it crosses your threshold - present your UIAlertView.

Comment: I can't give you a code snippet for a concept. I can add a link to Key-value-observing.